# persist in database is not working

Tags: symfony

i'm trying to add my data into my database , i was trying to not use a  formbuilder, inside that i put all my form into the controller,
but when i submit the button i did't got an error but i can't find my data in the database.
here is my code any one have an idea please.

```
   public function AjoutAction()
  {
    $classe=new Classes();
  $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $classe);    
    $formBuilder
  ->add('NomClasse', 'text')
  ->add('save',      'submit')
  ;
 $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
 if ($form->isValid()) {
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($classe);
  $em->flush();
    } return $this->render('MyAppSchoolBundle:Classe:ajout.html.twig',array(
  'form' => $form->createView(),
));


}
```

my twig file is here :

```
 <h3>Formulaire d'annonce</h3>
 {{ form(form) }}
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it to something like this:

```
public function AjoutAction(Request $request)
{
    $classe=new Classes();
    $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $classe);    
    $formBuilder
      ->add('NomClasse', 'text')
      ->add('save',      'submit')
    ;
    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $objToPersist = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($objToPersist);
        $em->flush();
    } 
    return $this->render('MyAppSchoolBundle:Classe:ajout.html.twig',array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: thank you, its working , but if explain to me , why i shoud add Request $request to the function ? and how the Handlerequest here.. thank you